# getting length of array for each element

Tags: javascript

how can i get forEach elements lengths which was checked in my if else statement?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-kkt7bc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
this.ages = [18, 20, 1];

this.ages.forEach((a) => {
  //infant
  if (a >= 0 && a <= 1) {
    this.id = 1;
    this.travel.listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange.push({
      travellerAgeRangeId: this.id,
      travellerCount: a.length,
    });
  }

  //adult
  else if (a >= 12 && a <= 59) {
    this.id = 3;
    this.travel.listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange.push({
      travellerAgeRangeId: this.id,
      travellerCount: a.length,
    });
  }
});
console.log(this.travel);
```

also i want to push with same **travellerAgeRangeId** only once but it is pushing twice.

output i get from console.log is:

```
listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange: [  
{travellerAgeRangeId: 3, travellerCount: undefined},
{travellerAgeRangeId: 3, travellerCount: undefined},  
{travellerAgeRangeId: 1, travellerCount: undefined} ]
```

output i wanna get:

```
 listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange: [  
 {travellerAgeRangeId: 3, travellerCount: 2}, 
 {travellerAgeRangeId: 1, travellerCount: 1} ]
```

Comment: A number doesn't have a `length` property? Do you just want the value?

Comment: use `this.travel.listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange.length` instead of `a.length`

Comment: hi! thanks for the comment. I wanna get the length of elements that returned true in if-else statement, for example, first if must return travellerCount: 1, second one travellerCount: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***Updated***

Although your approach is inappropriate for doing this but somehow i solved your problem; [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-zjhrsd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Globally declare your variable

```
infant = 0;
child = 0;
adult = 0;
```

Suppose you have array of ages like this

```
this.ages = [18, 20, 1, 11, 12, 0.2, 10];
```

Now you run a for loop to count infants, children, and adults.

```
for (let a = 0; a <= this.ages.length; a++) {
      if (a >= 0 && a <= 1) {
        this.infant = this.infant + 1;
      } else if (a >= 2 && a <= 11) {
        this.child = this.child + 1;
      } else if (a >= 12 && a <= 59) {
        this.adult = this.adult + 1;
      }
    }
```

and when running the foreach loop you can then reference your global variable like this:

```
this.ages.forEach((a) => {
      //infant
      if (a >= 0 && a <= 1) {
        this.id = 1;
        this.travel.listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange.push({
          travellerAgeRangeId: this.id,
          travellerCount: this.infant,
        });
      }
      //child
      else if (a >= 2 && a <= 11) {
        this.id = 2;
        this.travel.listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange.push({
          travellerAgeRangeId: this.id,
          travellerCount: this.child,
        });
      }
      //adult
      else if (a >= 12 && a <= 59) {
        this.id = 3;
        this.travel.listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange.push({
          travellerAgeRangeId: this.id,
          travellerCount: this.adult,
        });
      }
    });
```

---

> ***Old Version***

you are pushing element length in your `travellerCount` property which is not an `array`

All you need is get `this.ages` length

```
this.ages = [18, 20, 1];

this.ages.forEach((a) => {
  //infant
  if (a >= 0 && a <= 1) {
    this.id = 1;
    this.travel.listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange.push({
      travellerAgeRangeId: this.id,
      travellerCount: this.ages.length,
    });
  }

  //adult
  else if (a >= 12 && a <= 59) {
    this.id = 3;
    this.travel.listOfTravellerCountPerAgeRange.push({
      travellerAgeRangeId: this.id,
      travellerCount: this.ages.length,
    });
  }
});
console.log(this.travel);
```

Comment: Hi, i dont wanna get ages length, i wanna get length of elements that returned true in if else statement

Comment: for example, first if must return travellerCount: 1, second one travellerCount: 2

Comment: @GalathyniusAelin Updated my answer, check if it solves your problem: